# Java PDF generating library

Tags: java, report

Which Java PDF library to use in commercial project? I need to generate a *printable* (and good if it will be editable, like *.xls*) report (it contains table, some text and report's total page count - this is because I can't use HTML( I can't calculate page count)). 
P.S. I can't use iText because it's licence don't allow to use free version of iText in commercial projects.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for xls as well or what do you mean exactly? Editable pdf?

Comment: @Pulsar , I asking about PDF library, but it nice if someone suggest me other easy way to generate printable and editable report. Thanks

Comment: Windward (disclaimer I'm the CEO) can do exactly what you ask here. You can find it at https://www.windwardstudios.com/output-format/pdf (comment because closed to answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are in the same boat at my job, and are moving to [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). For what it's worth, generating real print quality PDFs (like, ones that get printed hardcopy by a print company) for office documents is somewhat non-trivial. In my experience, distiller does the best job. But PDFBox is certainly more straightforward if that will meet your print needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below three Java libraries to create HTML+CSS template to makeup your PDF file.
Flying-saucer + Freemarker + Itext

Flying-saucer:`https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/`

Freemarker: `http://freemarker.org/`

Itext 2.1.7: `http://itextpdf.com/` (Please note this is the free version of iText in commercial projects.)

You can also Check this project which is using these three libraries:

https://github.com/xiang-lee/pdf-generator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks Barranka, I edited the comment to provide the essential parts of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I have used [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) supports several output formats. You might also be interested in [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) it supports pdf, html, excel and openoffice.

Answer (score 2):

Apache PDFBox perhaps?

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

iText wasn't always under AGPL. You might consider using iText 2.7 or 4.2 which are under LGPL.

See also this question: [What is latest version of itext that is not AGPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl)